# Algorithm to optimize parameters based on imprecise fitness function

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, search

I am looking for a general algorithm to help in situations with similar constraints as this example :

I am thinking of a system where images are constructed based on a set of operations. Each operation has a set of parameters. The total "gene" of the image is then the sequential application of the operations with the corresponding parameters. The finished image is then given a vote by one or more real humans according to how "beautiful" it is.

The question is what kind of algorithm would be able to do better than simply random search if you want to find the most beautiful image? (and hopefully improve the confidence over time as votes tick in and improve the fitness function)

Given that the operations will probably be correlated, it should be possible to do better than random search. So for example operation A with parameters a1 and a2 followed by B with parameters b1 could generally be vastly superior to B followed by A. The order of operations will matter.

I have tried googling for research papers on random walk and markov chains as that is my best guesses about where to look, but so far have found no scenarios similar enough. I would really appreciate even just a hint of where to look for such an algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for fall in a broad research area called [metaheuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) (which include many non-linear optimization algorithms such as genetic algorithms, simulated annealing or tabu search).

Then if your raw fitness function is just giving a statistical value somehow approximating a real (but unknown) fitness function, you can probably still use most metaheuristics by (somehow) smoothing your fitness function (averaging results would do that).

Comment: This seems like a good place to search for appropriate algorithms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the [Metropolis algorithm](http://oscar.cacr.caltech.edu/Hrothgar/Ising/monte.html)?

This approach uses a random walk, weighted by the fitness function. It is useful for locating local extrema in complicated fitness landscapes, but is generally slower than deterministic approaches where those will work.

Comment: I think it would probably be better than random search, but it seems to not take the order into account and as you mention, it would probably get stuck in a local extrema. Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: Getting stuck in local extrema is addressable to some degree by (1) using a large initial step size or (2) using multiple initial vectors scattered randomly around the fitness space. But on further consideration I concluded that this is sub-optimal for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple Markov Chain

[Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), which you mention, aren't a bad way to go. A Markov chain is [just a state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Finite_Markov_chain_processes), represented as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) with edge weights which are transition probabilities. In your case, each of your operations is a node in the graph, and the edges between the nodes represent allowable sequences of operations. Since order matters, your edges are [directed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). You then need three components:

1. **A generator function** to construct the graph of allowed transitions (which operations are allowed to follow one another). If any operation is allowed to follow any other, then this is easy to write: all nodes are connected, and your graph is said to be [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). You can initially set all the edge weights to 1.
2. **A function to traverse the graph**, crossing *N* nodes, where *N* is your 'gene-length'. At each node, your choice is made randomly, but proportionally weighted by the values of the edges (so better edges have a higher chance of being selected).
3. **A weighting update function** which can be used to adjust the weightings of the edges when you get feedback about an image. For example, a simple update function might be to give each edge involved in a 'pleasing' image a positive vote each time that image is nominated by a human. The weighting of each edge is then normalised, with the currently highest voted edge set to 1, and all the others correspondingly reduced.

This graph is then a simple learning network which will be refined by subsequent voting. Over time as votes accumulate, successive traversals will tend to favour the more highly rated sequences of operations, but will still occasionally explore other possibilities.

#### Advantages

The main advantage of this approach is that it's easy to understand and code, and makes very few assumptions about the problem space. This is good news if you don't know much about the search space (e.g. which sequences of operations are likely to be favourable).

It's also easy to analyse and debug - you can inspect the weightings at any time and very easily calculate things like the top 10 best sequences known so far, etc. This is a big advantage - other approaches are typically much harder to investigate ("why did it do that?") because of their increased abstraction. Although very efficient, you can easily melt your brain trying to follow and debug the convergence steps of a [simplex crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)!

Even if you implement a more sophisticated production algorithm, having a simple baseline algorithm is crucial for sanity checking and efficiency comparisons. It's also easy to tinker with, by messing with the update function. For example, an even more baseline approach is pure random walk, which is just a null weighting function (no weighting updates) - whatever algorithm you produce should perform significantly better than this if its existence is to be justified.

This idea of baselining is very important if you want to evaluate the quality of your algorithm's output empirically. In climate modelling, for example, a simple test is "does my fancy simulation do any better at predicting the weather than one where I simply predict today's weather will be the same as yesterday's?" Since weather is often correlated on a timescale of several days, this baseline can give surprisingly good predictions!

#### Limitations

One disadvantage of the approach is that it is slow to converge. A more agressive choice of update function will push promising results faster (for example, weighting new results according to a power law, rather than the simple linear normalisation), at the cost of giving alternatives less credence.

This is equivalent to fiddling with the mutation rate and gene pool size in a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), or the cooling rate of a [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) approach. The tradeoff between 'climbing hills or exploring the landscape' is an inescapable "twiddly knob" (free parameter) which *all* search algorithms must deal with, either directly or indirectly. You are trying to find the highest point in some [fitness search space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_space). Your algorithm is trying to do that in less tries than random inspection, by looking at the shape of the space and trying to infer something about it. If you think you're going up a hill, you can take a guess and jump further. But if it turns out to be a small hill in a bumpy landscape, then you've just missed the peak entirely.

Also note that since your fitness function is based on human responses, you are limited to a relatively small number of iterations regardless of your choice of algorithmic approach. For example, you would see the same issue with a genetic algorithm approach (fitness function limits the number of individuals and generations) or a neural network (limited training set).

A final potential limitation is that if your "gene-lengths" are long, there are many nodes, and many transitions are allowed, then the size of the graph will become prohibitive, and the algorithm impractical.

Comment: If it wasn't for the parameters to the operations I would say this is a great solution. The parameters will probably be significant to the final beauty-score. Even if each operation only has a simple 8 bit parameter, this quickly makes the amount of edges to manage intractable.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much describing a genetic algorithm in which the sequence of operations represents the "gene" ("chromosome" would be a better term for this, where the parameter[s] passed to each operation represents a single "gene", and multiple genes make up a chromosome), the image produced represents the phenotypic expression of the gene, and the votes from the real humans represent the fitness function.

If I understand your question, you're looking for an alternative algorithm of some sort that will evaluate the operations and produce a "beauty" score similar to what the real humans produce.  Good luck with that - I don't think there really is any such thing, and I'm not surprised that you didn't find anything.  Human brains, and correspondingly human evaluations of aesthetics, are much too staggeringly complex to be reducible to a simplistic algorithm.

Interestingly, your question seems to encapsulate the bias against using real human responses as the fitness function in genetic-algorithm-based software.  This is a subject of relevance to me, since my namesake software is specifically designed to use human responses (or "votes") to evaluate music produced via a genetic process.

Comment: Actually I am specifically looking for an algorithm that will do well with real human inputs as the fitness function. Otherwise I would probably just throw computing power at the problem and do a random search.